# Use select statement result as variable and pass it to CTE and union all results from CTE

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

So i have a select statement for example `SELECT * FROM Group`. Lets say it has a column GroupId. I want to pass that GroupId data to a CTE and run CTE Multiple times until GroupId is Exhausted and also union all the rows I get from CTE for all GroupIds. How do I do this?

Below is just an simple example to help understand what I want to achieve. My actual CTE is more complex.

```
+-------+
|GroupId|
+-------+
|  10   |
|  450  |
|  265  |
|  266  |
+-------+
```

```sql
DECLARE @GroupId INT = 10;
    
WITH GroupCTE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM GroupCross
    where GroupCrossId = @GroupId
)
SELECT *
FROM GroupCTE
```

| GroupCrossId | GroupCrossName | GroupCrossParentId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | OCVJK | 1799 |
| 450 | OBYT | 486 |
| 265 | ONKU | 105 |
| 266 | ONCU | 84 |

Comment: Please include sample data in your question.

Comment: Added some sample GroupId. Is that enough?

Comment: Could you also provide desired sample output?

Comment: Added a sample output

Comment: i thought this is an easy sql question for sql experts. turns out i don't have a solution yet from anyone. i guess it a tough one

Comment: It would help if the data and/or query you provided showed how the data related. None of the GroupIDs in your input appear in your output, and no obvious relationship exists. Provide us with an explanation of the relationship and enough data to walk it through manually and we might be able to give you an answer.

Comment: @RobertSheahan i see what you are saying. Thanks. I updated them now so it makes more sense

Comment: I still don't understand your input, you just show GroupID but is your input table really (GroupID, GroupName, ParentGroupID) and you want to traverse the hierarchy and concatenate the group names? In the table below your query you show data that looks like it could be what I describe, but the GroupCrossParentID doesn't point to any rows in your table, is that an input or an output? If it's an input, would you show us where the GroupCrossParentID points, and if it's supposed to link to itself add some rows that are parents? And give desired output?

Comment: Group Table has GroupId and GroupName only as columns. GroupCrossParentId column has id's which are unrelated to columns in group table. No linking needed of any kind. i just need to loop through group id's from group table and go through CTE 4 times as in my example there are 4 group id's and get all results together like shown.i am thinking it needs a while loop and i have to put this CTE in stored proc.

Comment: `select *` in a cte is a very bad idea.

Comment: Why can't you just chain CTEs? First CTE gets the list of GroupIds from Group, second CTE in the chain has a where clause of `WHERE GroupID in (SELECT GroupID from first_cte)`.

Comment: OK, I think I follow so far, but one more question - what do you mean by "Aggregate"? Do you want to add up some value, string the GroupCrossName values together into a comma separated list, or something else.

Comment: @Shmiel my actual cte is more complex. and recursive. Just didn't want to post my actual long code here and complicate explanation

Comment: @LucasA.Meyer interesting i can try and then if it works i can put whole thing in stored proc to be called by back end C# application

Comment: @RobertSheahan Agregate is wrong word here. Sorry i corrected it. Union all is correct word here i think. Just union all the rows i get from each CTE run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on my earlier comment:

```
with ids as (
  SELECT GroupId from Group
),
GroupCTE as (
  SELECT *
  FROM GroupCross
  where GroupCrossId in (select GroupID from ids) -- join works here, too
)
SELECT *
FROM GroupCTE
```

I'm assuming that there's a reason why you can't simply join the tables.

Answer (score 1):

The following code outputs the correct results by passing in the GroupID to a stored procedure.  The stored procedure uses a CTE function.  The results from the stored procedure are inserted into a temp table, loops through each GroupID value/row, which then outputs all of the rows in one result set.

```
CREATE TABLE GroupTable
(
    GroupId INT,
    GroupCrossName VARCHAR(100)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE GroupCross
(
    GroupCrossId INT,
    GroupCrossParentId INT
)
GO

INSERT INTO GroupTable
VALUES
    ('10', 'OCVJK'),
    ('450', 'OBYT'),
    ('265', 'ONKU'),
    ('266', 'ONCU')

INSERT INTO GroupCross
VALUES
    ('10', '1799'),
    ('450', '486'),
    ('265', '105'),
    ('266', '84')

GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE GC
    @GroupID INT
AS
    WITH GroupCTE AS
    (
        SELECT
            C.GroupCrossId,
            T.GroupCrossName,
            C.GroupCrossParentId
        FROM GroupCross C
        JOIN GroupTable T ON C.GroupCrossId = T.GroupId
             AND C.GroupCrossId =
            (
                SELECT GroupId
                FROM GroupTable
                WHERE @GroupID = GroupId
            )
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM GroupCTE
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #GC

CREATE TABLE #GC
(
    GroupCrossId INT,
    GroupCrossName VARCHAR(100),
    GroupCrossParentId INT
)
GO

DECLARE @GroupID INT
DECLARE @i AS INT = 1
DECLARE @iMax AS INT =
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM GroupTable
)   

WHILE @i <= @iMax
BEGIN
    SET @GroupID =
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 GroupCrossId
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                GroupCrossId,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GroupCrossId ASC) AS 'RowNumber'
            FROM GroupCross
        ) R
        WHERE R.RowNumber = @i
    )

    INSERT INTO #GC
    EXEC GC @GroupID
    
    SET @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT * FROM #GC
```

Comment: Sorry but I need CTE here. as my actual CTE is more complex and recursive . i didn't show it here

Answer (score 1):

I think this is simpler than you fear.

Just use a JOIN:

```
WITH GroupCTE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM GroupCross AS c JOIN Group AS g 
      ON c.GroupCrossId = g.GroupId
)
SELECT *
FROM GroupCTE;
```

I understand you said your real CTE is more complex, and involves a recursive CTE. It should still be possible to use a JOIN in the initial part of the recursive CTE (before the UNION).

Answer (score 1):

**Unrelated data ??**
It is a bit confusing for me to catch all that is in the question and comments. There
are some contradictory statings as well as namings. Anyway, if I stick to the question
where we can found (quote):
"...I want to pass that GroupId data to a CTE and run CTE Multiple times until GroupId is Exhausted
and also union all the rows I get from CTE for all GroupIds."

Additionally, one of the comments says (quote):
"Group Table has GroupId and GroupName **only** as columns.
GroupCrossParentId column has id's which are **unrelated to columns in group table. No linking needed of any kind.**"

I understand that every record in cte should be joined/concatineted/crossed with each group_id.
For the given four group_ids and four parent_ids - This means 16 rows.
Please, could you confirm if those two datasets  are related (through GroupId) or not. I asume they are not and
if so, then this is what I could offer as an answer.

If I got it right - than all that you should do is just remove where clause in your cte definition and add
Inner Join to group_ids ON(1=1) in your main select.  In your main select you should add column(s) from joined dataset.
This way you'll get all the combinations (without using union) which can be
filtered later (if needed) in where clause of the main Select.

First the unrelated sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tbl_Group AS
        (   
            Select  10 "GROUP_ID", 'OCVJK'  "GROUP_NAME" From DUAL Union All
            Select 450 "GROUP_ID", 'OBYT'  "GROUP_NAME" From DUAL Union All
            Select 265 "GROUP_ID", 'ONKU'  "GROUP_NAME" From DUAL Union All
            Select 266 "GROUP_ID", 'ONCU'  "GROUP_NAME" From DUAL
        ),
    tbl_GroupCross AS
        (
            Select 1799 "PARENT_ID", 'Parent name (1799)' "PARENT_NAME" From DUAL Union All
            Select 486  "PARENT_ID", 'Parent name (486)'  "PARENT_NAME" From DUAL Union All
            Select 105  "PARENT_ID", 'Parent name (105)'  "PARENT_NAME" From DUAL Union All
            Select 84   "PARENT_ID", 'Parent name (84)'   "PARENT_NAME" From DUAL 
        ),
```

Then in cte just remove WHERE clause...

```sql
    grp_cross_cte AS
        (
            Select
                gc.*
            From 
                tbl_GroupCross gc
        )
```

select * from cte (joined to GroupId data) will give you all 16 combinations

```sql
SELECT 
    g.GROUP_ID "GROUP_CROSS_ID",        -- additional column from joined data
    g.GROUP_NAME "GROUP_CROSS_NAME",    -- additional column from joined data
    gc.* 
FROM 
    grp_cross_cte gc
INNER JOIN      
    (   SELECT GROUP_ID "GROUP_ID", GROUP_NAME "GROUP_NAME" FROM tbl_Group ) g ON(1=1)
--
--  R e s u l t:
--
--  GROUP_CROSS_ID GROUP_CROSS_NAME  PARENT_ID PARENT_NAME      
--  -------------- ---------------- ---------- ------------------
-- 1            10 OCVJK                  1799 Parent name (1799) 
-- 2           450 OBYT                   1799 Parent name (1799) 
-- 3           265 ONKU                   1799 Parent name (1799) 
-- 4           266 ONCU                   1799 Parent name (1799) 
-- 5            10 OCVJK                   486 Parent name (486)  
-- 6           450 OBYT                    486 Parent name (486)  
-- 7           265 ONKU                    486 Parent name (486)  
-- 8           266 ONCU                    486 Parent name (486)  
-- 9            10 OCVJK                   105 Parent name (105)  
--10           450 OBYT                    105 Parent name (105)  
--11           265 ONKU                    105 Parent name (105)  
--12           266 ONCU                    105 Parent name (105)  
--13            10 OCVJK                    84 Parent name (84)   
--14           450 OBYT                     84 Parent name (84)   
--15           265 ONKU                     84 Parent name (84)   
--16           266 ONCU                     84 Parent name (84)
```

This way every record from your complex cte will be present in the resulting dataset as many times as there are GroupIds.

The problem with this crossed data is that you can't directly get the resulting set of rows such as shown in your question, though all those rows are here. The reason is that the **data are unrelated,** if they are!? To do that we should know the logic behind
that resulting data. Regards...

Answer (score 1):

**If data are related** then you can get it if you remove where clause from cte and change your main select like below.

```sql
WITH
    tbl_Group AS
        (   
            Select  10 "GROUP_ID", 'OCVJK'  "GROUP_NAME" From DUAL Union All
            Select 450 "GROUP_ID", 'OBYT'  "GROUP_NAME" From DUAL Union All
            Select 265 "GROUP_ID", 'ONKU'  "GROUP_NAME" From DUAL Union All
            Select 266 "GROUP_ID", 'ONCU'  "GROUP_NAME" From DUAL
        ),
    tbl_GroupCross AS
        (
            Select 10 "GROUP_ID", 1799 "PARENT_ID", 'Parent name (1799)' "PARENT_NAME" From DUAL Union All
            Select 450 "GROUP_ID", 486  "PARENT_ID", 'Parent name (486)'  "PARENT_NAME" From DUAL Union All
            Select 265 "GROUP_ID", 105  "PARENT_ID", 'Parent name (105)'  "PARENT_NAME" From DUAL Union All
            Select 266 "GROUP_ID", 84   "PARENT_ID", 'Parent name (84)'   "PARENT_NAME" From DUAL 
        ),
    grp_cross_cte AS
        (
            Select
                gc.*
            From 
                tbl_GroupCross gc
        )
SELECT 
    GROUP_CROSS_ID,
    GROUP_CROSS_NAME,
    PARENT_ID "GROUP_CROSS_PARENT_ID"
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            g.GROUP_ID "GROUP_CROSS_ID",        
            g.GROUP_NAME "GROUP_CROSS_NAME",
            gc.PARENT_ID,
            gc.GROUP_ID
        FROM 
            grp_cross_cte gc
        INNER JOIN      
            (   SELECT GROUP_ID "GROUP_ID", GROUP_NAME "GROUP_NAME" FROM tbl_Group ) g ON(1=1)
    )
WHERE GROUP_CROSS_ID = GROUP_ID
--
--  R e s u l t
--
--  GROUP_CROSS_ID GROUP_CROSS_NAME GROUP_CROSS_PARENT_ID
--  -------------- ---------------- ---------------------
--              10 OCVJK                             1799 
--             450 OBYT                               486 
--             265 ONKU                               105 
--             266 ONCU                                84
```

The resulting dataset has the same 16 rows as in my previous (unrelated data) answer but here you can get your specific data using where clause in the main select. Without Where clause you have all combinations - every record from your cte is present in the final dataset as many times as there are GroupIds. Regards...